# Windows 7 ram and virtual memory

Tags: windows-7, resource-monitor

I have windows 7 64 bits professional edition OS. I was looking at resource manager the other day and noticed that even thought i have about 1 gb of available ram there was still about 48 hard faults.  I am curious about why did this happen and why the system did not use available 1gb of memory.

Comment: What items have the hard faults?  there are some system kernal items and systems own programs that will page out junk they will not be needing (my way of saying it)  immediatly even when 28gig of memory is still available. in those cases it is not use of available memory, it is not needed for re-use, except mayby on closing, leaving.

Comment: capture a xperf trace of the pagefaults: http://pastebin.com/MVdhhLUD and I can see what happens.

Comment: I will look exactly what processes create hard faults and post it.